# Tablesorter and date mm/yyyyy

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I've been using tablesorter a lot in my website like this

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
                widgets: ['zebra'], 
                dateFormat: 'uk', 
});
```

But i've a problem with date in the format : **MM/YYYY** (it's when I don't have the day I prefer showing **12/2005** than **00/12/2005**).

This format does not work with tablesorter dateFormat uk. How to make it working ?

And the difficulty is that I can have in the same table differents formats like this :

```
Date - Title
11/2005 - Movie 1
12/11/2005 - Movie 2
2006 - Movie 3
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [add a custom parser](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html):

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    id: 'rough-date', 
    is: function() { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        // format to look like an ISO 8601 date (2005-11-12).
        // Month-only dates will be formatted 2005-11.
        return s.split('/').reverse().join('-');
    }, 
    type: 'text' // sort as strings
});
```

And then use it like this (where `0` is the column number that contains the date):

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({ 
    headers: { 
        0: {
            sorter:'rough-date' 
        } 
    } 
});
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbuckley/3qv8euva/).